# jQuery Mobile Panel does not close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application wich uses a jQuery Mobile multipage layout. On every page (page A and page B) I have a navbar for switching between pages. No custom code involved. I also have a panel on every page which opens by clicking the 'new' button in the header.

Sometimes it happens that I hit the button (maybe to soft? or to fast?) to open to panel but the buttons just changes it state to "active" and the panel does not open. I cannot click the button anymore. When I change the page and go back (all by using the navbar) page A appears again and now the panel is opened. This is a strange behaviour but could be plausible. But trying to close it now is just impossible. Clicking one of the buttons in the panel is as inactive as clicking on the page itself. The whole thing seems to be froozen.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="one">
        <div data-role="header" data-transition="fixed">
            <a href="#panel_one" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">New</a>
            <h1 class="header">myApp</h1>
            <a href="#popup_one" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="false" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="slidedown" onclick="menu();">Options</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Header -->

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel_one">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" class="menu"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Panel -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-transition="none" class="ui-btn-active" >A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-transition="none" >B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- Page One-->

    <div data-role="page" id="two">
        <div data-role="header" data-transition="fixed">
            <a href="#panel_two" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">New</a>
            <h1 class="header">myApp</h1>
            <a href="#popup_two" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="false" data-transition="slidedown" class="ui-btn-right"  onclick="menu();">Options</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Header -->

        <div data-role="panel" id="panel_two">
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" class="menu"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Panel -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#one" data-transition="none">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two" data-transition="none" class="ui-btn-active" >B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- Page Two-->
```

`menu()` creates the content of the Menu which is not shown in the example. Another method (`loadPanel()`) is boud to the pageshow-event and will populate the sidebar with the buttons. every button will execute

```
var pageId = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");
$("#panel_" + pageId).panel('close');
```

before anything else is executed. However, all of this works most of the time and I would just like to know if some observed a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

As per jQuery mobile documentation

> A panel must be a sibling to the header, content and footer elements inside a jQuery Mobile page. You can add the panel markup either before or after these elements, but not in between.

Maybe you should move up your panel because it may be the cause of the strange behaviour

Comment: I don't really know if this solves the problem, because it happens often unexpected, but at least it will not harm to stick to rules.